# Changing cycler order in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
from cycler import cycler
cycler('color', 'rgb') * cycler(marker=['s', 'o']) * cycler('ls', ['-', '--', '-.', ':'])
```

In the above code, the lines plotted will use the color red 8 times (for different combinations of line style and marker), followed by color green 8 times...

is there a way to instead us color red with marker `s` and line style `-` followed by color green with marker `s` and line style `-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of cyclers is non cummutative, as it is the outer product of the cyclers. See [the cycler documentation](https://matplotlib.org/cycler/).

Therefore you might want to put the color last in the multiplication.

```
cycler(marker=['s', 'o']) * cycler('ls', ['-', '--', '-.', ':']) * cycler('color', 'rgb')
```